# iOS Incompatible pointer types returning NSDictionary from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdictionary

I'm having an issue where I use  NSMutableDictionaries returns values from NSDictionary.

Here is the warning message:

> incompatible pointer types returning 'NSDictionary *' from a function
>   with result type 'NSMutableDictionary *'

Here is the code:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)dictionaryWithContentsAtPath:(NSString *)path 

{

if ([path rangeOfString:@"/SessionStore"].location == 0) 
{

return [_inMemoryCache objectForKey:[path stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 13) withString:@""]];

}

if ([path rangeOfString:@"/PermanentStore"].location == 0) 

{

return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[self.persistentStoragePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[path substringFromIndex:15]]];

}

return nil;

}
```

Please help me how to resolve this warning.

Comment: Why do you set a `NSMutableDictionary` as the return of your method (there:`-(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionaryZzZ`) if you return a `NSDictionary` (`return [NSDictionary ZzZ`)?

Comment: you should return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:_your_NSDictionary_];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure you're returning the right type. Your method states it's returning an `NSMutableDictionary`, but then returns only an `NSDictionary`.

Try this instead:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsAtPath:(NSString*)path {

    if ([path rangeOfString:@"/SessionStore"].location == 0) {
        return [[_inMemoryCache objectForKey:[path stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 13) withString:@""]] mutableCopy];
    }

    if ([path rangeOfString:@"/PermanentStore"].location == 0) {
        return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[self.persistentStoragePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[path substringFromIndex:15]]];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Note: added a call to `mutableCopy` to turn your literal `NSDictionary` into a mutable version, and in the second case, used called the `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile` method on the `NSMutableDictionary` subclass instead of the `NSDictionary` parent class.